Room Design With Slight Variations?
I'm working a pcb with multi voltage regulators on one board. For the duplicate voltage regulators, I'm using rooms to duplicate the routing and layout. However, for some of the peripheral components, I'll swap out different valued components, sometimes adding multiple components to substitute for one on the original reference room. Is there a way to preserve the layout and routing as much as possible for similar but not identical rooms in Altium?

You can use snippets but I don't think that's exactly what you want. I am not aware of a way to create variations without making a change to each design.
You could potentially add variants to a room, but you still have to go make the change anyway. The easiest way is to copy as much as you can with a manual copy or snippets and then make the changes to the variations. With PCB there isn't a way to create variants that I'm aware of (with the exception of footprint variants which would probably not be quicker after creating multiple footprints)

I'm actually having multiple regulators on the same board, and I want to have the same regulators with different peripherals on the side. I'm currently using rooms. I edited my question so hopefully its more clear.
